# Setting title of each view not working

Tags: ios, swift, xcode6

Hierarchy:
Navigation Controller
Tab Bar Controller goes to a table view controller and a view controller
The table view controller goes to a detailed view controller

I am trying to set the title of both views that come off of the tab bar controller, but can only set the title of the tab bar controller and table view controller. The table view controller title doesn't show up when only that has it set, but when I put a title on the tab bar controller, it goes to both the view controller and the table view controller. Also, the view controller coming from the tab bar controller, won't even let me click in the view and change the title.

Thoughts?

Comment: Sorry but I could not understand the view hierarchy you are drawing. Could you please elaborate more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this code in view did load

```
navigationBar.topItem.title = "some title"
```